# Method to find out if someone is logging a conversation on Yahoo Messenger

Tags: yahoo-messenger

just wondering if there was a way to stop, or at the very least tell if someone is logging a text conversation on Yahoo Messenger.

Answer (score 6):

In theory, it's impossible to tell, because it's like sending a postcard in the mail: the message is right there and you don't have to do anything to read it if you can intercept it. My suggestion is to install the [Off the Record](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/) plugin for Pidgin and get your chat partner to do so too, which encrypts your entire chat with a throwaway key so that after the chat the log is unrecoverable.