# How to find out if my IM messages are encrypted?

Tags: encryption, pidgin, yahoo-messenger

I'm a Yahoo Messenger addict and I use it extensively with Pidgin on Debian. Unfortunately I moved to a place where I have to share a privately operated network connection with a lot of people I'm not really familiar with.

Without having details about the network architecture I think it would be really easy to monitor network traffic here.

I use https connections for all my mails, university stuff and social networks, so I'm not too afraid about those sites.

However it is a nightmare of mine that someone could read my private IM conversations and I didn't find any information about how the Yahoo Messenger is implemented on Pidgin and if my conversations are encrypted.

Can anyone help how to find out?

Comment: Related: [Method to find out if someone is logging a conversation on Yahoo Messenger](http://superuser.com/questions/175349/method-to-find-out-if-someone-is-logging-a-conversation-on-yahoo-messenger?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To monitor your network you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). It's the most popular software to analyse your incoming and outgoing network traffic.

And I think you will find out Yahoo Messenger is sent in clear text format... But it's great to find it out yourself what's encrypted and what's clearly visible for everybody!

Comment: I doesn't seem to be available for Linux :-(

Comment: It is using `sudo apt-get install wireshark` in terminal :-)

Comment: @NickvanTilborg you can use `tcpdump` in linux does the same as wireshark and is probably built in.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark is a quick way to tell. In addition, if your IM traffic is in the clear, you can use a ssh proxy back to your home (or somewhere else) to encrypt your internet traffic, or even an OpenVPN setup. This will encrypt *all your outgoing traffic*, including your IMs.

Comment: I try to connect to my university VPN once, but it didn't work :-| 
Seems like some ports are blocked...

Comment: If you *really* want to secure your internet traffic, and don't care about bandwidth, you can setup your own OpenVPN server at home, and connect to it from anywhere. It's a fair amount of work, but it's worth it imo.